# Расшифровка сообщений CAN шины. Реверс-инжиниринг

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, can

У меня есть лог файл, состоящий из строк вида:

```
RX 1       SFF 0x510      8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x10 0
```

где:
`RX` - индикатор принятого сообщения;
`1` - порядковый номер принятого сообщения;
`SFF` - индикатор стандартного формата фрейма;
`0x510`      - ID сообщения;
`8` - длина сообщения (количество байт);
`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x10` - данные сообщения;
`0` - время прихода сообщения (в ms) относительно старта записи лога.

Так же известно событие, которое в этом логе отражено. Например, статус центрального замка. За время записи лога он был в таких состояниях: `01010`, где `0` – открыт, а `1` – закрыт.

Необходимо найти соответствующие `ID` блоков и байты данных, в которых эти статусы отражены. На текущий момент я отсортировал все по `ID`, создав ассоциативный контейнер `map`, в котором ключом является `ID`, а значением структура, хранящая вышеописанные данные, извлекаемые из каждого сообщения. Из контейнера были удаленны все `ID`, сообщения которых не меняются с течением времени, а так же те, в которых происходило 3 и меньше изменений в данных за время записи лога. И тут встала проблема, как анализировать дальше. Перебрать все данные глазами, в отладчике, например – можно, но это не гарантия, что найду именно нужные мне данные, т.к. есть несколько подходящих вариантов. Важное уточнение, что никаких данных касательно марки и модели авто или возможных значений нет, программа должна быть универсальна и работать с логом обозначенного формата, то есть, есть только лог и только то, что в нем нужно найти. Может кто знает, как это можно вырвать из лога, а не снимая данные с авто в реальном времени

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, какие категории данных известны. Так как упоминается только событие, то буду исходить из этого. Дальше я бы сгруппировал данные по событиям, для каждого события вывел количество собщений, список состояний, количество сообщений с каждым состоянием.

Comment: Аргументируйте -1, пожалуйста

Comment: Не совсем уловил ход мысли, из всего возможного набора нам известно лишь одно событие, где и как оно проявляется – нужно найти. То есть, в объеме сообщений реально выделить ID, то есть, условно, блоки автомобиля (например, фара, блок управления, блок комфорта). По ID все сообщения я уже отсортировал, то есть, вижу, какие сообщения отсылал каждый блок. Но ситуация такова, что один блок может уведомлять о разных событиях, соответственно, в логе много информации, как периодически повторяющейся, так и высплывающей по факту какого-либо действия, и что там за информация, помимо искомой, неизвестно.

Comment: После ID нужно выделить, сколько различных сообщений отправляет каждый ID. Потом уже анализировать эти группы